# A simple linear model is not converging

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

For sake of exercise, I want to write a simple network to simulate the "minimum" function f(x,y) = min(x,y), I restrict the values of input to integers between 0 and 100. Here's my code to accomplish this:

```
class myMinFun(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(2, 4)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(4, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.lin2(x)
        return x

model = myMinFun()
crit = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
max_int = 100
min_int = 0

for epoch in range(100):
    x1 = np.random.randint(low=min_int, high=max_int, size=10).astype(np.float32) / max_int
    x2 = np.random.randint(low=min_int, high=max_int, size=10).astype(np.float32) / max_int
    x = torch.tensor(np.column_stack((x1, x2)))
    y = torch.tensor(np.minimum(x2,x1)).unsqueeze(1)
    y_h = model(x)
    loss = crit(y_h, y)
    print(loss.item())
    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    # with torch.no_grad():
    #     print(model.lin1.weight)
    #     print(model.lin1.bias)
    #     print(model.lin2.weight)
    #     print(model.lin2.bias)
    optimizer.step()
```

I know that the model should converge to the values below, as setting the weights manually to these values result in 0 loss:

```
# with torch.no_grad():
#     model.lin1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[1,1],[1,-1],[-1,1],[-1,-1]], dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)
#     model.lin1.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0,0,0,0], dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)
#     model.lin2.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5]], dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)
#     model.lin2.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0], dtype=torch.float32), requires_grad=True)
```

But my model is not converging to these value, I tried different learning rates. What could cause the issue?

Comment: You just need to train longer. I ran for 20000 batches and it achieved a loss of 1e-14

Comment: nice this worked, it was issue with how many iterations I ran it for!

Comment: i have tested with Adam optimizer and it converges faster with that. `optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)`.